# To change the value of passByValue from false to true in esb

Tags: jboss, esb, jboss-esb

I obatained the below mentioned part in my console when I used systemPrintln action in jboss esb by giving printfull option as true.

Can anyone help me to change the **passByValue : false** to **true** so that i may get the contents present in the soap header to get print on my console.

```
header: [ To: InVMEpr [ PortReference < <wsa:Address      
invm://5072655175616c696669636174696f6f6e2424242424242424242424244170706f6e746d656e74417661696c6162696c697479/false?false#10000/>, 
<wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:type : urn:jboss/esb/epr/type/invm/>,     
<wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:passByValue : false/> > ] 
 ReplyTo: InVMEpr [ PortReference < <wsa:Address invm://thread-179-30/>,    
<wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:type : urn:jboss/esb/epr/type/invm/>, 
<wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:passByValue : false/>,
 <wsa:ReferenceProperties jbossesb:temporaryEPR : true/> > ] 
 MessageID: a7b662aa-a7bd-43e6-85cc-c85d065b0381 ]
```

Comment: How is this related to soapUI?

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana I will get the above response if I run XML request using soupUI